# Check two columns conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.2 PHP framework. This is so odd that the code is correct, but it's always return unexpected boolean value.

```
$enjoying = (DB::table('enjoy')->where('user_id','=',$authUserId)->where('video_id','=',$video_id)->get()) ? true : false;
```

I'm so sure that I have a table called "enjoy" where user_id and video_id is matches exactly the above statement. But it returns false always unexpectedly.

On the other hand, I also created a Enjoy Model, so I replace and modify the above statement.

```
$enjoying = (Enjoy::where('user_id','=',$authUserId)->where('video_id','=',$video_id)->get()) ? true : false;
```

This time again, assume my table 'enjoy' don't have any data. But it will unexpectedly returns TRUE always. I have no idea what's going on.

**Enjoy Model**

```
<?php
class Enjoy extends Eloquent
{
protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'video_id');

protected $table = 'enjoy';

public  $timestamps = false;
  public function users() {
       return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User');
  }
}
```

Comment: `get()` isn't going to return a `false`-y value like you seem to think it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$data = Enjoy::where('user_id','=',$authUserId)->where('video_id','=',$video_id)->get();

echo $enjoying = (count($data)) ? 1 : 0;

or 

echo $enjoying = (count($data)) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the "exists" method?

```
$enjoying = Enjoy::where('user_id','=',$authUserId)
    ->where('video_id','=',$video_id)
    ->exists();
```